# Does LineageOS or OpenGApps have a GMS License and GMS Certification?

Tags: google-play-store, lineageos, google-apps

Some time ago, I have installed [LineageOS on my Samsung Galaxy S2](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/i9100), together with the OpenGApps suite. I have registered with Google and enjoy access to the phletora of Google Play apps on this phone.

Now, **is this use of Google Play from an ASOP based Android legal**, or problematic? Since, I really doubt [LineageOS](https://lineageos.org/), nor the [OpenGApps](https://opengapps.org/) project has properly gone through the [GMS License and GMS Certification which seems to be required to obtain proper access to Google's apps](https://www.android.com/gms/)?

Note: This question has arisen around the Ban of Huawei from using "Google services" as per this article: https://www.theguardian.com/technology/2019/may/19/google-huawei-trump-blacklist-report

I think, Huawei should be no different than LineageOS, when it comes to using ASOP and installing the play store via OpenGApps.

Answer (score 1):

Google's stance is that GMS is granted to a device, which then stays with it regardless of any custom ROM the consumer may install. In other words, if you get a stock device that has GMS, then you're allowed to install OpenGApps on any third-party ROM you put on it. However, you're not allowed to install OpenGApps on a device that never had GMS.

Comment: Do you have links to relevant documentation?